# SAS_Add value for specific rows

Tags: sas

I want to give the value for some specific rows. I think showing it by example would be better. I have following datasheet;

```
 Date                 Value
01/01/2001          10
02/01/2001          20
03/01/2001          35
04/01/2001          15
05/01/2001          25
06/01/2001          35
07/01/2001          20
08/01/2001          45
09/01/2001          35
```

My result should be:

```
 Date                 Value    Spec.Value
 01/01/2001          10        1
 02/01/2001          20        1
 03/01/2001          35        1
 04/01/2001          15        2
 05/01/2001          25        2
 06/01/2001          35        2
 07/01/2001          20        3
 08/01/2001          45        3
 09/01/2001          35        3
```

As you can see, my condition value is 35. I have three 35. I need to group my date by using this condition value.

Comment: Spec.Value should be equal 1 for ALL values until first 35. Spec. Value should be equal 2 for ALL values between first 35 and second 35. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
  set have;
  retain specvalue 1;
    if lag(value) = 35 then do;
      specvalue +1;
      end;
run;
```